# How do I disallow a viewcontroller from progressing to the next view in my app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I have a multi-view application and in my storyboard I have graphically defined a view (view1: log in username/password view for instance) that will segue to another view (view2: welcome view for instance) with a button click. In view1, when the user enters the user name and password information and clicks on the "Log in" button, it will go through some logics to check the validity of the username and password, and will proceed to the welcome view if successful. However, how do I refrain the view switching if the username or password is invalid and I want the user to stay in the current view1 that will now have a popup notifying the invalid username or password?

Thanks.

Kenny

Comment: If you post some code, it is a lot more helpful for us to know what exactly you need help with. Otherwise we can only assume.

Comment: My question is that since I am using storyboard to define the segue from view1 to view2, which handles the transition from view1 to view2 when my button UI is clicked on, I want to know how to not allow the transition if my existing logic to check username/password fields returns false. Peter's solution below will work, but I need a solution for iOS 5+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for example the segue was called login then something like the following will accomplish it (iOS 6 + only).

```
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
     if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"login"]){
          //my logic code here populating logged_in with a boolean value showing if logged in or not
          if(logged_in) {
               return YES;
          } else {
               return NO;
          }
     }
     // Make sure all other segue's can still work.
     return YES;
}
```

Comment: I actually need the app to run under iOS 5. Any suggestion on how to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should test if the user name is valid or not, and go from there.

```
if(usernameIsValid == TRUE){//Here you want to do your "logics to check the validity"
//Switch Views
}
else{
//Show A UIAlertview letting user know credentials are invalid. 
}
```